# Finding key value with lodash from localstorage

Tags: local-storage, lodash

I have a simple array

```
var questionFoo = {
        'questionFoo': {
            av1: 1,av2: 1,av3: 1,av4: 1,av5: 1,av6: 1,av7: 1,av8: 1,av9: 1,av10: 1,av11: 1,av12: 1,av13: 1,av14: 1,av15: 1,
            av16: 1, av17: 1, av18: 1, av19: 1, av20: 1, av21: 1, av22: 1, av23: 1, av24: 1, av25: 1, av26: 1, av27: 1,
            av28: 1, av29: 1,av30: 1, av31: 1, av32: 1, av33: 1
        }
    }
```

I want to find the value based on a variable that is the key. For example

```
function getFooValue(fooItem) {
        var mainFoo = localstorage.getItem('questionFoo')

        // Now with lodash i want to find say av6 which is being passed in 
        // as fooItem
        var keyFoo = _.find(mainFoo.questionFoo,fooItem).value(); 
    }
```

I basically just want the value 1 returned but based on item that is being passed in

thanks

Comment: As easy as var value = mainFoo.questionFoo[fooItem], no need to use lodash for that.

Comment: well that is embarrassing ... thank you .